# Error in List comparing "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'" python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

```
list1 = [['happy'], ['happy'], ['neutral'], ['happy'], ['neutral']]
list2 = ['happy', 'happy', 'happy', 'happy', 'happy']
```

Want to get count that same value in same position in two lists, here it should be `'3'`. I tried from

```
(list1 == list2).sum()
```

But getting an error.

```
(list1 == list2).sum()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Can anyone say how can I fix this.

Comment: What? What is that code intended to do? What are you trying to sum?

Comment: `x == y` yields True or False.  You're then calling `.sum()` on that result, which doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to be expecting NumPy array behavior out of Python lists (though even if you were using NumPy arrays, your shapes would be messed up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [['happy'], ['happy'], ['neutral'], ['happy'], ['neutral']]
list2 = ['happy', 'happy', 'happy', 'happy', 'happy']



print sum(1 for a, b in zip(list2, list1) if a == b[0])
```

Comment: Why rebind `list1` here? Surely, `if a == b[0]` is better here?